# Spark: rename multiple columns with alias

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I've got data frame with following schema:

```
| -- comment: struct
|   |-- _1: string
|   |-- _2: string
|   |-- _3: string
```

When I use `df.select("comment.*")` I'm getting data frame with columns _1, _2, _3. Is there any possibility to change aliases using `alias` method? Ideally it would look like `df.select($"comment.*".alias("a", "b", "c"))`?

Even `df.select($"comment".alias("a"))` produces an error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Invalid usage of '*' in expression 'alias';
```

Comment: `df.select($"comment.*").toDF("a", "b", "c")` or some variant of it might work for this...

Comment: @Alec I know about that, but if I had other columns in select, that toDF() would be so long

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always generate a sequence of columns for `select`:

```
val from = (1 to 3).map(i => col(s"comment._$i"))
val to = Seq("a", "b", "c")

df.select(from.zip(to).map { case (x, y) => x.alias(y) }: _*)
```

Comment: quite elegant :)